# drawing line between two dots in image matrix

Tags: image, matrix

I have a matrix with 0's as a background and 1's as objects and I am trying to connect two 1's at a distance with a line consisting of 1's as well. In other words, I want to replace 0's with a minimal amount of 1's in order to connect the two 1's. Any ideas for an algorithm to find the elements that construct the path between two elements in a matrix?

Comment: I presume you mean Bresenham's Line Drawing Algorithm... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm

Comment: Yes, this is it. Thanks!